# Unwrap ansible result variable

Tags: ansible

This is something I often do

```
- name: check whether ready
  shell: do_something_complex
  changed_when: false
  ignore_errors: true
  register: result

- name: make it ready
  when: result.rc != 0
```

It is messy when there are many tasks after that, which perform the same check.

I would like instead to wrap the result somehow, and use it like this:

```
- name: do this if ready
  when: isReady

- name: do that if not ready
  when: not isReady
```

How can I do that? (Preferably without intermediate dummy tasks that exist just to set variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the thing that [`import_tasks:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing-task-files), or even custom modules, are designed to solve:

```yaml
# tasks/make_ready.yml
- name: check whether ready
  shell: '{{ check_ready_shell }}'
  changed_when: false
  # you'll want to be **very careful** using this
  ignore_errors: true
  register: isReady

- name: make it ready
  shell: '{{ make_ready_shell }}'
  when: isReady.rc != 0
```

then, in your main playbook:

```yaml
- import_tasks: make_ready.yml
  vars:
    check_ready_shell: echo 'hello from checking'
    make_ready_shell: systemctl start-the-thing-or-whatever

- import_tasks: make_ready.yml
  vars:
    check_ready_shell: echo 'hello from other checking'
    make_ready_shell: systemctl start-the-other-thing
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good alternative to what i wanted to do. But, is there a way to do this without intermediate steps like you've shown. A way to just "create a variable" from another variable?

Comment: Sure, one can easily create a variable from another variable, but your follow-up sounds like maybe the question wasn't clear -- can you try [updating your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61012555/edit) to show an example of what syntax you are expecting? I thought you were trying to avoid repeating the ansible boilerplate around test-and-take-action

Comment: I want to be able to use `isReady` instead of `result.rc != 0` - i.e. for the former to equal the latter. Is that possible? I know I can write an intermediate task that does that sort of assigning (`when` true/false and then `register` corresponding variable), but I was hoping there is a simpler way available?

Comment: Who is setting `isReady` and do you want **one** global `isReady` or you mean `nginxIsReady` and `sshdIsReady` type deal? You have a scenario in your head that is not being written down

Comment: But I will go ahead and tell you that without a custom module "without intermediate dummy tasks that exist just to set variables" is not going to happen -- ansible is not a programming language -- you have to run a task in order to create variables

Comment: Yep that's what I feared. Thanks for the alternative.